# $injector:modulerr Failed to instantiate module ng due to $$SanitizeUriProvider() is not a constructor

Tags: angularjs

Getting below exception, after upgrade from 1.3 to 1.5, which happens only on fewer older safari browsers, i know $$SanitizeUriProvider is already part of the bundle, any input appreciated.

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
'function $$SanitizeUriProvider() {
    [native code]
}' is not a constructor
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1='function%20%24%24SanitizeUriProvider()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bnative%20code%5D%0A%7D'%20is%20not%20a%20constructor
```

Comment: if you are upgrading to 1.5 then why does it print https://errors.angularjs.org/ **1.7.7**

Comment: actually it happens for both 1.5 and 1.7, this one is log from 1.7